# ALSA "default" vs "hw:0,0"

Tags: c, linux, alsa

What is the difference between the devices "default" vs "hw:0,0" ? Are they the same ?

(Background: I faced some trouble to play audio when I configured hw:0,0 , but "default" worked. Could not find what caused this)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `default` device uses the `plug` plugin to automatically convert sample formats and rates, and typically alsa uses the `dmix` plugin to allow multiple applications to access the device at the same time.